# How to get first value of row in table on click?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have one table with first numeric column:

```
<table id="toppings"  border="1" cellpadding="2">
   <tr id="id1">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>row12</td>
      <td>row13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="id2">
      <td>12</td>
      <td>row22</td>
      <td>row23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="id3">
      <td>15</td>
      <td>row32</td>
      <td>row33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="id4">
      <td>22</td>
      <td>row42</td>
      <td>row43</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="id5">
      <td>23</td>
      <td>row52</td>
      <td>row53</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="id6">
   <td>55</td>
   <td>row62</td>
   <td>row63</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get first value/column of row on clicking row. 
I found following example doing the same.

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?522104-HTML-table-on-click-event

But  I don't want to add event to each row manually as my table is having billions of records. Please help me. How can I get the row value (first column) on clicking row?

Comment: You really should describe the user-story or the purpose your after. Which problem are you trying to solve. What you are describing here sounds confusing…

Comment: I hope it doesn't have "billions" of records that might take the browser a really long time to render...

Comment: You could try using jQuery adding on onclick by class. Just give all your rows the same class then add onclick to that class using jquery...

Comment: Add a single click listener to the table, find the clicked row within a loop by checking `.parentElement` from `e.target` and then changing the object to its `parentElement` untill a row is found (jQuery would make this simple, no need for looping). Finally read `innerHTML/textContent` from the first cell on the found row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#toppings tr").click(function(){
   alert( $(this).children().closest("td").html());
});
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/k1ezbcrk/

Comment: @user15662 I thought you don't want to add a listener to every row?

Comment: He said he didn't want to add code manually for each row, as in targeting by each TR id.

Comment: Is there any way where i can avoid this? It will be better if it is possible.

Comment: alternative syntax for the click callback: `alert($(this).children('td:first').html());`

Comment: @xe4me No magic, delegation: `$('#toppings').click(function (e) {console.log($(e.target).closest('tr').find('td').html());});`

Answer (score 0):

example for one row could be

```html
<tr id="id2">
      <td><a  href="#" onclick="getColumnValue(this)">12</a></td>
      <td>row22</td>
      <td>row23</td>
  </tr>

<script>
 function getColumnValue(elem){
  alert(elem.innerHTML);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: He said : "But i don't want to add event to each row manually as my table is having billions of records"

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#toppings tr").click(function(){
      alert( $(this).children().first().html());
  });
```

Comment: Can i convert alert( $(this).children().first().html()); as numerical variable as i need to pass this as parameter.

Comment: of course , the value is number , you can assign it to a variable and use it however you want

Answer (score 0):

You could use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

function getValue(){
  console.log(event.target.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerText);
}

table.addEventListener('click', getValue, false);
```